# Based on the user credential load the module in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7

I have created one school based application in that 3 different modules are there.teacher module, parent module and student module.
Now the problem is like memory of the application is more bec i have integrated 3 modules in single app it self.
Is it possible while launching the app we are asking the "who iam?", after selecting the user then we can download only that module.Remaining thing we can keep it in suspend mode.I don't think so this will work.My client wants the app size less.

if anyone knows please help me.

Comment: not possible to change the app structure dynamically!

Comment: Thanks for replaying .....and then how we have to manage this kind of apllication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [On-Demand Resources Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/On_Demand_Resources_Guide/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015083)

App Thinning is new feature available from XCode 7. You can refer [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AppThinning/AppThinning.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH35) for more detail

Using this your app will have only those resources which are required for initial time late you can get resources base on your module using on-demand resources.

This will helpful to optimize your app size.